# Match a line in multiple files and modify

Tags: regex, bash, sed

If anyone is good with regex patterns, replacing strings and bash - you could do me a big favour:

I have a bunch of source files in a directory that have this line in various places. The line may well be preceded by spaces.

> RELEASE_AND_NIL(_theNameOfAVariable);

I want to convert all occurences, overwriting the files with:

> [_theNameOfAVariable release];

..any pointers please? I think someone showed me how to do this before with sed, but I forgot it was that long ago.

Thanks

EDIT

The actual command I used in the end was: (Thanks to @fardjad)

```
 find . -name '*.m' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/RELEASE_AND_NIL(\(.*\))/[\1 release\]/g"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `sed -i` to perform in-place replacement and the regex replace pattern would be:

```
s/RELEASE_AND_NIL\((.*?)\)/\[\1 release\]/g
```

so you can do:

```
sed -ie "s/RELEASE_AND_NIL(\(.*\))/[\1 release\]/g" /path/to/your/file
```

and if you have bunch of source files, you can use `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ie "s/RELEASE_AND_NIL(\(.*\))/[\1 release\]/g"
```

Comment: Almost there, getting some weird errors - i've added the details to my post for clarity

Comment: @bandejapaisa sorry, I forgot to put `s` on regex. I edited my answer.

Comment: @bandejapaisa you're welcome, I forgot to mention, `sed -ie` may create additional files ending with `e`. AFIK there is no workaround on Mac unless you use `gnu-sed` (Install with `MacPorts` or HomeBrew) with `-i -e` instead of `-ie`.

Comment: Yes, i noticed the files ending in e, so I removed that flag and used -i "" (I read that mac requires the quotes if you don't want a backup file, and it didn't work without them). See my edited question for the actual command I used.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 'RELEASE_AND_NIL\(([^(]+)\)/[\1 release]/' your_file.txt > target_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that _theNameOfAVariable might be anything, then this should do what you need:

```
sed -e 's/ *RELEASE_AND_NIL(\(.*\));/[\1 release];/'
```